# Detect Whether User Is Running Sales Or Service Cloud On Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

We have a formula field against contact records in Salesforce that needs to be different based on whether the record is being viewed in the Sales Cloud or the Service Cloud Console.

Is there a way to detect whether you are running under Sales Cloud or Service Cloud so the formula can be substituted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure you cannot do this using a formula field.
You can do this in custom code/controller by checking the URL parameter named isdtp , if you are in console it will be set to 'vw' or 'nv'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the end I decided to make things work the same in both Sales and Service Cloud to be safe.